# Reduce vs Fold for String Concatenation in Rust

Tags: rust, functional-programming

Since 1.51, Rust has included `reduce`, which I'm used to from Scala.
`fold` works like foldLeft in Scala, but reduce is different. What am I getting wrong?

This works beautifully:

```
let ss = vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter()
.fold("".to_string(), |cur, nxt| cur + nxt);

println!("{}", ss);
```

This does not:

```
let ss = vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter()
.reduce(|cur, nxt| cur + nxt);

println!("{}", ss);
```

Errors:

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `&&str` to `&&str`
 --> src/main.rs:3:28
  |
3 |     .reduce(|cur, nxt| cur + nxt);
  |                        --- ^ --- &&str
  |                        |
  |                        &&str

error[E0277]: `Option<&&str>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 |     println!("{}", ss);
  |                    ^^ `Option<&&str>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Option<&&str>`
  = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
  = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=839d803fe43cc54a29247ab293d9d003)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the docs for `fold`: _"Note: `reduce()` can be used to use the first element as the initial value, if the accumulator type and item type is the same."_ -- But `String` and `&str` are not the same type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first one you're starting with `"".to_string()` which is an owned `String`. `String` implements [`Add<&'_ str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20str%3E) which lets you concatenate other borrowed `&str` strings with the `+` operator.

Writing the parameter types out lets you see the difference between `cur` and `nxt` clearly:

```
let ss = vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter()
    .fold("".to_string(), |cur: String, nxt: &&str| cur + nxt);
```

The `reduce()` call, on the other hand, works purely with `&str`s, but `&str` doesn't support concatenation with `+`. There's no `Add` impl.

```
let ss = vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter()
    .reduce(|cur: &str, nxt: &str| cur + nxt); // &str + &str not defined
```

While `&str` doesn't support concatenation, `String` does, because it can do it efficiently. `a + b` consumes `a`, re-using its buffer for the result `String`. It doesn't have to allocate `O(a.len())` space nor spend `O(a.len())` time copying the existing contents of `a`. `b` is simply appended in-place to `a`'s buffer.

Therefore, if you convert the borrowed `&str`s to owned `String`s it compiles:

```
let ss = vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter()
    .map(|s| s.to_string())
    .reduce(|cur: String, nxt: String| cur + &nxt)
    .unwrap();
```

Notice also that `reduce()` returns an `Option<String>` which needs to be unwrapped.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I ran some tests, and found `map` and `reduce` to be an order of magnitude slower for string concat. Interestingly, `fold` is as fast as `.concat()`